# Onclick button method in fragment

Tags: java, android

I created simple application in android. I have a user profile in navigation drawer. when choose address option in that drawer Open that fragment (Example:Address fragment). In that layout i put save button. While click that save button i want validate all the fields. But, when i choose that option from the drawer, application unfortunately stopped.

My code here:

AddressFragment.java

```js
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AddressFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText line2;
    Button addrsave;
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_address, container, false);

        addrsave = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addrsave);

        // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
  AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_autoCompleteTextView);
  // Get the string array
  String[] city = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city);
  // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);

  textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        addrsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String addr = line2.getText().toString();
                if (addr.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Field cannot be left blank.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

 return view;

  }


}
```

My logcat:

```js
07-22 12:47:46.235    6355-6355/com.h2o E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.h2o, PID: 6355
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.h2o/com.h2o.AccountActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.h2o.AddressFragment.onCreateView(AddressFragment.java:38)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please anyone help!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: your button is add in fragment XML

Comment: Also initialize `line2` which will throw an exception of NPE once you resolve the first issue

Answer (score 4):

Change this line

```
addrsave = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addrsave);
```

to

```
addrsave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addrsave);
```

Your `R.layout.fragment_layout_address` is assigned to `view` so you have to use `view` variable to get the button from layout. Secondly, Also initialize `line2` which will throw an exception of NPE(Null Pointer) once you resolve the first issue

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
addrsave = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addrsave);
```

to this:

```
addrsave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addrsave);
```

Problem is that you are doing findViewById() on getActivity() which gives you a `null`. And then setting an `onClickListener` on it will throw NullPointerException.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

I cant see where you have initialized `line2` ? 
So `line2` is null which might cause the exception

```
String addr = line2.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added button in fragment and you are trying to retrive it from activity. So change retrieving the view from getActivity() to view like below

```
addrsave = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addrsave);
```

Replace the above with the following line

```
addrsave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addrsave);
```

And You missed the line2 view initialization in line number 38